# Android openGL es 2.0 touch and object position bug... clueless

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch, coordinate

My application is made with openGL ES 2.0 on android and i'm having a rather serious problem with object position updates. My game loop is like this, Draw all objects --> update game object positions --> iterate. However, i have 2 different kind of position updates: one kind that is calculation based, that when a value is low or high enough, it will change direction. The other kind is touch based, when the user touch at any position and/or swipes the screen, the object will follow.

Now to the problem. When the user touches the screen and/or swipes, the objects that is supposed to only respond to touch also gets the changing x value of the calculation based objects, and i'm clueless as to why this is since they use entirely different position variables.

The code that follows here is an excerpt from the GLsurfaceView showing how the touch position values are passed into the GL renderer

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
    if(e != null){
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            if(_renderer != null){
                queueEvent(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        _renderer.touchInput(x, y);
                    }

                });
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            if(_renderer != null){
                queueEvent(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        _renderer.touchInput(x, y);

                    }

                });


            }

        }
```

The code that follows here is an excerpt from the GL renderer that shows how the touch values enters the renderer and is converted to world coordinates.

```
public void touchInput(float x, float y){
    y = (float)_view[3] - y;
    GLU.gluUnProject(x, y, -1.5f, _ModelMatrix, 0, _ProjectionMatrix, 0, _view, 0, touch_to_world_coords, 0);

    _world_x = touch_to_world_coords[0] * touch_to_world_coords[3];
    _world_y = touch_to_world_coords[1] * touch_to_world_coords[3];
}
```

Next up is the code that calculates the new position of the non-touch object

```
public void updateObjectCoords(){
    _test_x += 0.05f;
            _test_y += 0.05f;
}
```

and finally the onDrawFrame from the renderer which im using as a game loop.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glContext) {
    //Tell OpenGL to use this program when rendering.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(_current_shaderProgramHandle);

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Sets the active texture unit to texture unit 0
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    //Bind the texture to current unit
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _TextureDataHandle);

    //Tells texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by binding it to unit 0
    GLES20.glUniform1i(_TextureUniformHandle, 0);

    //Draw square, gets coordinates from gluUnproject method
    Matrix.setIdentityM(_ModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(_ModelMatrix, 0, _world_x, _world_y, -1.0f);
    drawSquare();

    //Draw square, gets coordinates from updateObjectCoords method
    Matrix.setIdentityM(_ModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(_ModelMatrix, 0, _test_x, _test_y, -1.0f);
    drawSquare();


    //GLES20.glUseProgram(_point_shaderProgramHandle);
    //drawLight();
    updateObjectCoords();

}
```

edit: noticed my bad explenations so im adding this instead to be more clear what happens when :)

(When cube 1 gets touch input and cube 2 gets coordinates from updateObjectCoords):
Application starts:
  everything work as expected, cube 2(updateObjectCoords one) moves as expected.
User touches screen:
  cube2 continue to move as its supposed to, cube1(touch controlled) coordinate data seem to get mixed with cube2 as its movements become seemingly twice as large and towards the same direction as cube2, you can still manipulate it a bit but its not very responding.

(Cube2 is made to be static, however updateObjectCoords are still active and is called on every frame to update the value of _test_x and _test_y):
Application starts: 
  everything is just as expected
User touches screen:
  everything works perfectly

So it seems that it is specificly the continually relocating of cube2 thats interfering with the positioning of cube1.

hope this have made matters more clear! :)

Why does the coordinates of one object to be drawn effect all other translateM's? How come all other objects doesnt get effected by the touch coordinates?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with OpenGL ES 2.0, but I know in older versions of OpenGL you must save the current View Matrix (push it onto the stack) before you apply model transformations to it.  After you push it to the stack, apply your model transformations then draw the model.  Once you're done, pop the matrix back off the stack.  Repeat for EVERY object.  Annoying but as is the State Machine that is OpenGL..

Comment: Thanks ALOT for the comment, really nice to get some response :) i wont pretend i know exactly what your referring to however the problem does seem to be like you says that something still seems to be active in whatever translateM does. Currently looking into how to take something "off the stack", what this stack is and if it might help my case. Thanks a lot for the direction mate! :)

Comment: I've now looked at a number of different android openGL es 2.0 tutorials for android. Everyone seems to be doing the drawing as i am. Havent seen any removing from stacks or such yet. Also i've now tried to make different objects go to different places with the calculation method and everything works just perfectly. Only problem is when touch, like i mentioned before, the touch controlled objects go ballistic. it has to be something with the touch implementation itself as everything works perfectly until you touch the screen. With static objects, touch work fine. This is so wierd :(

Comment: [http://sscce.org/](http://sscce.org/). Strip your code from _anything_ distracting you from the problem. The abundant use of globals makes reasoning hard. -- Don't know if that's the problem, but `_world_x/y` is modified by `touchInput` and used for the ModelView of two objects. Note further that `_ModelMatrix` is reused over and over again, and then just used for `GLU.gluUnProject`. This doesn't look correct.

Comment: first of all, thanks alot for your input. Dont i need the same modelmatrix in the gluUnproject to get proper touch conversion results? The tutorials i've looked at have used the same model matrix for everything but ill try using different ones and see if it helps :)

Comment: tried changing so they used diffrent model matrixes, same result still :(

Comment: draw a line from the results `GLU.gluUnProject` is giving you. The line should go straight into the plane, so you should not be able to see it until you move the camera or world. That will tell you whether the problem is with `GLU.gluUnproject` or something else

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just switching the drawing of cube1 with cube2. This seems to have solved everything. Assuming that drawing the touch controlled objects last will end the interference :D

Comment: Bah! its not solved :( after some additional fiddling around i still have issues with this